# Reverse String?

Tags: python

I've been stuck on this task for hours and when I find Python code to reverse my stguess (which is a variable that stores the users input from a HTML file) I get error after error. Some of which pretty much state it doesn't understand the reverse methods like stguess[::-1] stguess.reversed() it just doesn't work. Also I have a stupid "if != 1" I was actually supposed to find a way to ensure only a-z and A- Z could be entered but again I didn't know how to do that so I just entered in that so I knew I could pass the value and try to work on reversing it. ok well doing:

```
if guess != 1:
            print''.join(reversed(stguess)) //But this does not reverse the string?

import webapp2
import os
import jinja2
import logging
from google.appengine.api import users


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')))
extentions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape']
user = users.get_current_user()


class reverse(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    logout_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.path)
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('reverseword.html')
    stguess = self.request.get('content')
    msg = ''
    template_values = {
        'user': user.nickname(),
        'url_logout': logout_url,
        'url_logout_text': 'Log Out',
        'guess': stguess,
        'guess_text': msg,
        }
    if user:
        stguess = self.request.get('content')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.url))

def reverse(text):
    if len(stguess) <= 1:
        return stguess
```

## class reversepost(webapp2.RequestHandler):

```
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    logout_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.path)
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('reverseword.html')
    stguess = self.request.get('content')
    msg = ''
    template_values = {
        'user': user.nickname(),
        'url_logout': logout_url,
        'url_logout_text': 'Log Out',
        'guess': stguess,
        'guess_text': msg,
        }
    if user:
        stguess = self.request.get('content')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.url))

def post(self):
    logging.info("post")
    logout_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.path)
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('reverseword.html')
    stguess = self.request.get('content')

    if user:
        logging.info("user found")
        msg = ''
        guess = -1
        try:
            guess = str(stguess)
            logging.info("guess contains "+str(guess))
        except:
            guess = -1
        **if guess != 1: //if guess is not equal to 1
            return stguess.reverse()** //return user input.reversed()
        else:
            msg = 'Didnt work'
        template_values = {
        'user': user.nickname(),
        'url_logout': logout_url,
        'url_logout_text': 'Log Out',
        'guess': guess,
        'guess_text': msg,
        }
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.url))
```

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', reverse)
], debug=True)

Comment: This is a purely Python question and has nothing to do with GAE. Plus, almost all of that code is irrelevant to the question: you should extract the relevant code only.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ''.join(reversed(stguess))
```

will just *print* a reversed version of the string.

If you want to *store* the value, you need to rebind stguess to the reversed value. ie.

```
stguess = stguess[::-1]
print stguess
```

or

```
stguess = ''.join(reversed(stguess))
print stguess
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your reply. Nice and easy to follow, I'll try the stguest = stguest[::-1] but when I tried stguest[::-1] Google app engine pretty much said it didn't understand [::-1] but maybe in a variable it will. Also I'll try the second as Google app engine seems to be fine with the. .join(reversed so maybe storing that as a variable first and then print may make it work.  I shall report back tomorrow, thanks again!